# Move data from Firestore Database (not Realtime Database) to new collection in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to transfer data from a document belonging to one collection to another. It doesn't matter how to do this (rename the sub-collection in the document, or copy the data and then delete it).

I know about one example, but I need a detailed analysis of it, preferably with an example.

The same example:

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            moveFirestoreDocument();
        }
    });
}
public void moveFirestoreDocument(DocumentReference fromPath, final DocumentReference toPath) {
    fromPath.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document != null) {
                    toPath.set(document.getData())
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                    fromPath.delete()
                                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                                }
                                            })
                                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                }
                            });
                } else {

                }
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Code with moving a specific record:

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CollectionReference addToCartRef1 = firestore.collection("AddToCart");
                DocumentReference addToCartRef2 = addToCartRef1.document(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                CollectionReference addToCartRef3 = addToCartRef2.collection("Product");
                DocumentReference fromPath = addToCartRef3.document("DiaSef1RX9xlAFm26P8M");

                CollectionReference deletedAddToCartRef1 = firestore.collection("AddToPurchased");
                DocumentReference deletedAddToCartRef2 = deletedAddToCartRef1.document(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                CollectionReference deletedAddToCartRef3 = deletedAddToCartRef2.collection("Product");
                DocumentReference toPath = deletedAddToCartRef3.document("DiaSef1RX9xlAFm26P8M");
                moveFirestoreDocument(fromPath, toPath);
            }
        });
```

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqHgO.png)

[Continuation of the database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTnqU.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What's the problem with the code you shared? Which specific line doesn't do what you want it to do? Is there any error message?>

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo, What should be the information of the method in the "delete" button? How exactly to assign collections for "fromPath" and "toPath"?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, Same questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How exactly to assign collections for "fromPath" and "toPath"?

The "fromPath" and "toPath" are **not** collection references, but document references. Since the `moveFirestoreDocument()` method contains two arguments, you have to call the method and pass two document references as arguments. So assuming you have two collections that look like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- products (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- $productId (document)
   |            |
   |            --- //Document details.
   |
   --- deletedProducts (collection)
         |
         --- $productId (document)
                |
                --- //Document details.
```

To move a document from one collection to the other, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference productsRef = db.collection("products");
DocumentReference fromPath = productsRef.document(productId);
CollectionReference deletedProductsRef = db.collection("deletedProducts");
DocumentReference toPath = deletedProductsRef.document(productId);
moveFirestoreDocument(fromPath, toPath);
```

Comment: But the application crashes, and the information does not move. The database structure is attached to my question. Have I made a mistake somewhere?
                CollectionReference addToCartRef = firestore.collection("AddToCart");
                DocumentReference fromPath = addToCartRef.document(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                CollectionReference deletedAddToCartRef = firestore.collection("AddToPurchased");
                DocumentReference toPath = deletedAddToCartRef.document(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                moveFirestoreDocument(fromPath, toPath);

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Besides that, please also provide a more detailed database screenshot and add the code to your question, not as a comment. It's hard to read it that way.

Comment: Sorry, everything works fine, but with a specific record... I need to move all the records (as shown in the second picture). Is it realistic to implement?

Comment: Yes, it is. You should call the same method for each document you want to be moved.

Comment: And how to do this without knowing the specific product identifier? The user places an order and the program itself sends the goods from the cart to the purchased

Comment: It's very simple, iterate the collection where the documents are present, get each document ID and use it further to create the references.

Comment: May I ask you for a piece of code? I attached the code for a specific record to the question. I will be very grateful

Comment: In general, other questions that derive from the initial question should be added separately here on StackOverflow. So please post a new question, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72366973/how-to-move-all-records-from-one-location-to-another-in-firestore-database-andr)

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.