# How to move all records from one location to another in Firestore Database (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to move all Firebase database records (not a specific record with an id) from a specific location to another. Code for moving certain records:

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        CollectionReference addToCartRef1 = firestore.collection("AddToCart");
                        DocumentReference addToCartRef2 = addToCartRef1.document(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        CollectionReference addToCartRef3 = addToCartRef2.collection("Product");
                        DocumentReference fromPath = addToCartRef3.document("DiaSef1RX9xlAFm26P8M");
        
                        CollectionReference deletedAddToCartRef1 = firestore.collection("AddToPurchased");
                        DocumentReference deletedAddToCartRef2 = deletedAddToCartRef1.document(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        CollectionReference deletedAddToCartRef3 = deletedAddToCartRef2.collection("Product");
                        DocumentReference toPath = deletedAddToCartRef3.document("DiaSef1RX9xlAFm26P8M");
                        moveFirestoreDocument(fromPath, toPath);
                    }
    });
```

Database structure:

[image: Database structure 1],

[image: Database structure 2 (continuation)]

Comment: As Doug mentioned in his answer, you have to iterate through the `Products` collection and call the method from the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72354128/move-data-from-firestore-database-not-realtime-database-to-new-collection-in-a), to move each particular document to another location.

Comment: But I need to move not each particular document separately in the collection, but all at once

Comment: There is no way you can move a collection with all the containing documents at once.

Comment: I puzzled for a long time how to do this, but still defeated the problem. Attached the solution to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method: [Move data from Firestore Database (not Realtime Database) to new collection in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72354128/move-data-from-firestore-database-not-realtime-database-to-new-collection-in-a)

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                firestore.collection("AddToCart").document(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .collection("Product")
                        .get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            QuerySnapshot tasks1 = task.getResult();

                            CollectionReference addToCartRef1 = firestore.collection("AddToCart");
                            DocumentReference addToCartRef2 = addToCartRef1.document(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                            CollectionReference addToCartRef3 = addToCartRef2.collection("Product");

                            CollectionReference deletedAddToCartRef1 = firestore.collection("AddToPurchased");
                            DocumentReference deletedAddToCartRef2 = deletedAddToCartRef1.document(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                            CollectionReference deletedAddToCartRef3 = deletedAddToCartRef2.collection("Product");

                            for (DocumentSnapshot doc1: tasks1.getDocuments()) {
                                DocumentReference fromPath = addToCartRef3.document(doc1.getReference().getId());
                                DocumentReference toPath = deletedAddToCartRef3.document(doc1.getReference().getId());

                                moveFirestoreDocument(fromPath, toPath);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not have any "move" operation for documents.  What you will have to do is:

1. Query for each document you want to move
2. Iterate the results and copy them into new documents in the new collection
3. Delete the original documents